# Spring jpa: add field to @Entity class. Should this result in the automatic addition of a new column in the underlying table?

Tags: database, spring, postgresql, jpa, ddl

I have a class that is an entity using spring jpa.

I want to add a new field to this class. A private boolean with getter/setter methods.

I have heard that I should be able to just add the field to the class and spring jpa should add the column to the underlying table on next run.

The behaviour that I am actually seeing is that it throws an error.

Is anyone familiar with this operation? Is it true that spring jpa should handle the column addition automatically?

Comment: JPA has different versions (2.0 is very popular and 2.1 is getting its way) and different implementations. The answer depends on those things.

Comment: Spring Data has nothing to do with that it has all to do with the JPA implementation you use and how you configured that. However doing so is nice for your local dev environment, I would strongly recommend against it in a production environment!